# Leaflet - Marker does not stop moving even after removing Event Listener

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using the [leaflet-realtime](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime) plug in in to visualize a trajectory.
I replicated [the trail code](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime/tree/master/examples) and tried to remove the trail and the marker by adding `realtime.removeEventListener();`
However, the marker is still moving. I know I can remove the marker by adding `realtime.removeLayer(marker);` but what about the trail?

I tried to remove it by adding `trailCoords = [];` but it doesn't work either.
This is the slightly modified code of `trail.js`

```
    var trailCoords;
    var map = L.map('map'),
        trail = {
            type: 'Feature',
            properties: {
                id: 1
            },
            geometry: {
                type: 'LineString',
                coordinates: []
            }
        },
        realtime = L.realtime(function(success, error) {
            fetch('https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/')
            .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
            .then(function(data) {
                trailCoords = trail.geometry.coordinates;
                trailCoords.push(data.geometry.coordinates);
                trailCoords.splice(0, Math.max(0, trailCoords.length - 5));
                success({
                    type: 'FeatureCollection',
                    features: [data, trail]
                });
            })
            .catch(error);
        }, {
            interval: 250
        }).addTo(map);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var i = 0;
    realtime.on('update', function() {
        console.log(i)
        i++
        map.fitBounds(realtime.getBounds(), {maxZoom: 3});
        if (i === 3)
        {
            trailCoords = [];
            realtime.removeEventListener();
        }

    });
```

My question is what part of the code is being executed if I stop the event listener and how can I remove the trail?

Comment: I've not used this particular plugin, but the docs mention that there are `getFeature` and `getLayer` methods, which take the key of your feature as its argument.  In your case that would look like `realtime.getLayer(trail)`.  Have you tried using this?  You could call `realtime.getLayer(trail).remove()`.

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging and this is what I found.  If you examine the `realtime` object, the marker and the trail are both properties of that object, under the `_featureLayers` property.  You need to define to `id` of these layers as part of the `properties` of the GeoJSON:

```js
var trail = {
  type: 'Feature',
  properties: {
      id: 'trail'
  },
  geometry: {
      type: 'LineString',
      coordinates: []
  }
}
```

You can see I changed the `1` to `trail`.  Now you can grab your trail and remove it by calling `realtime.getLayer('trail').remove()`.  I'm not having much luck getting `removeEventListener` to work, but realtime comes with a `stop` function that seems to be working.  It will look like this:

```js
var i = 0;
realtime.on('update', function() {

    console.log('i', i)
    i++
    map.fitBounds(realtime.getBounds(), {maxZoom: 3});
    if (i === 3) {
        trailCoords = [];
        realtime.stop();
        realtime.getLayer('trail').remove()
    }

});
```

For some reason the default `id` name of the marker itself is undefined.  You could potentially call `realtime.getLayer('undefined').remove()` to remove it, but that's very hacky, and assumes there are no other layers with an `undefined` id.  There may be some way to define that `id` for the default maker, but I'll leave that to you.

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-realtime-trail-issue-8jc0x)

Answer (score 0):

To remove features, the easiest is to just no longer provide those features to the `success` callback.

So, to remove the trail, you would add some condition under which the trail should no longer be visible and call `success` like this:

```
                success({
                    type: 'FeatureCollection',
                    features: [data, trail]
                });
```

Likewise, if you want to remove the marker as well, call success with empty `features`:

```
                success({
                    type: 'FeatureCollection',
                    features: []
                });
```